# dynamically removing JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I've read a number of threads and questions about this subject but can't seem to come up to a workable solution to the problem.  below is the code for the methods used to add and remove the component.

```
public void addAuxPanel (String pType, int pStart, int pEnd) {

    int id = mPanels.size();
    int xPos = PANEL_START_X;
    int yPos = PANEL_START_Y + (PANEL_HEIGHT * id) + 15;

    if (id == 0) {
        xPos = PANEL_START_X;
    }

    String type = pType;
    int start = pStart;
    int end = pEnd;

    AuxPanel p = new AuxPanel(type, start, end, id, this);
    mPanels.add(p);

    p.setBounds(xPos, yPos, 300, 25);

    getRootPane().add(p);
    getRootPane().repaint();
    getRootPane().revalidate();
}

public void removeAuxPanel (AuxPanel pPanel) {

            getRootPane().remove(pPanel);
            getRootPane().revalidate();
            getRootPane().repaint();

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  *"..no layout to get the elements on the panel where I want them."* That is probably the core of the problem.  Once the layout is gone, expect all sorts of surprises.  Use layouts with padding and borders on components to achieve a layout that is both exactly right for the screen and PLAF, *and* robust.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do `frameObject.remove(yourPanel);`

than do your normal revalidate() and repaint().

A small code for your help here :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TwoPanels extends JFrame {

    public TwoPanels() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        final JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        JButton button = new JButton("ADD AND REMOVE PANEL");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (panel1.isShowing()) {
                    remove(panel1);
                    add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                } else if (panel2.isShowing()) {
                    remove(panel2);
                    add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });

        add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new  Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TwoPanels();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you wanted to remove a component from the JPanel, see this code remove() still works for this :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TwoPanels extends JFrame {

    public TwoPanels() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("I am a JLabel");
        panel1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel1.add(label);

        JButton button = new JButton("ADD AND REMOVE PANEL");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (label.isShowing()) {
                    panel1.remove(label);
                    panel1.revalidate();
                    panel1.repaint();
                } else {
                    panel1.add(label);
                    panel1.revalidate();
                    panel1.repaint();
                }
            }
        });

        add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        pack();
            setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new  Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TwoPanels();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. When I only call remove() the object isn't removed from the JPanel.  As I understand, revalidate() is used to get the container redrawn.  I also should mention that the container is a subclassed JPanel and has no layout assigned as I'm using WindowBuilder with no layout to get the elements on the panel where I want them.  I'm aware that this is frowned upon, but frankly if those classes weren't as clunky, I'd be happy to use them.

Comment: @strangeInAStrangerLand : You want to remove a JPanel or something on the JPanel?

Comment: I have an object which is a subclass of JPanel that I want to remove from another object which is also subclass of JPanel.  The container adds and removes the child class.  I have a listener in each child class that listens to see if its been clicked and if so it calls the container's remove method on itself.

Comment: The problem I have is that I was already calling add() then revalidate() then repaint() but not seeing a change.  That was my original question: if I'm calling all 3 of these methods why doesn't my object add/remove from the panel?

Comment: Clarify me please, on the thing you said : "Once clicked, you call the container's remove method on itself" or you mean  that you calling the container's remove method to remove the child class which has been clicked upon.

Comment: Might be you not using EDT, watch my main method. SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...), that is the key for this I guess. That's is used to Schedule a job for your event dispatcher thread, put your code that is responsible for creating and showing GUI in this or call the method which does the creating and showing part of GUI.

Comment: That's exactly right.  Each image added has a listener that when clicked calls the parent's remove() method passing a reference of itself as a parameter.  the parent container then handles the business of removing the element.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm just going to refactor the project.  I'm not using a layout as they're clunky and not worth the trouble of dealing with for this project.  I attempted using invokelater() to the same result as before.  Frankly, the problem is not worth the time spent trying to find a solution when I can just try another approach.  Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: @strangeInAStrangerLand : Ahha, I am still trying to find an answer to the solution, but if you may post a bit of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of the problem, I will appreciate that, to confirm as to what I am thinking or trying is exactly what you want.

Comment: @mKorbel : Thankyou :-), but seems like the issue is tough

Answer (score 1):

How about calling `panel.setVisible (false)` ?

Comment: The panels need to be added and removed at runtime rather than just being set to visible or not.  The idea is that if a user clicks the image, it will be removed from the JPanel it's stored in.

Comment: that should be most efficient way +1

Comment: @strangeInAStrangerLand put image as Icon to the JLabel, there any reasons for that, read relevant tutorials http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it doesn't fit what I'm trying to do.  What I'm looking to do is add and remove elements dynamically.  I know this can be done within swing, but the repaint/revalidate methods don't seem to be getting it done.